# Microsoft Android Face API Error

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services

When I am debug face API throw below error.

UnknownHostException@830035410936} "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.projectoxford.ai": No address associated with hostname"

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try to use the latest version of [client library for Android](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Face/Android). There have been some API URL changes when Project Oxford became Cognitive Services (not with the hostname, though).

You can also want to check that your app can access internet altogether (i.e. it is allowed by application manifest).

Answer (score 0):

Face API (and all Cognitive Services) have changed the REST URIs to:

[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com

example:

westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

This change was made ~4 months ago. The `ProjectOxford-ClientSDK` project on GitHub hasn't been maintain for over a year so doesn't include the URI change (and many other changes)